# Initializing & navigating through Dictionaries / multi-dimensional arrays in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Swift Dictionary / multi-dimensional array syntax. I'm trying to initialize `tableData` and insert a new `tableData.myList` object using:

```
var tableData = ["myNumber":nil, "myList":[]]
tableData["myList"].insert(["label" : "Example Label A", "timestamp" : NSDate()], at: 0)
```

Which generates this error:

```
Value of type 'Array<Any>??' has no member 'insert'
```

Here's a sort of javascript sketch of what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/L9s5amer/

Comment: Give it a try. Update your question with details about whatever specific issue you are having.

Comment: I've been playing with it for the past few hours and generated a slew of different errors / crashes, but it's not quite clicking.  This should be relatively straight forward with the right structure.  I'm approaching like arrays in Javascript, where it seems like Swift wants to see something different.

Comment: Your "multi-dimensional array structure" is not a "multi-dimensional array structure" at all. It's a dictionary containing an array of dictionaries

Comment: Post your best attempt and clearly point out any errors and which line is causing them. People are happy to help you solve your coding issue but less happy to just write your code for you.

Comment: @arby Why are you using dictionaries for this? You seem to have static keys. Why not use a struct or a class?

Comment: Got it, it seemed like this was the quickest / most concise way to ask the question for a simple answer.  Let me give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: @Alexander I want to store a number and a list of a key : value pairs into `defaults` and then read them back.  Under the hood, this is populating a TableView.  This syntax might be wrong (I haven't quite grasped the ?!??!! thing yet.) . Let me sketch up what I'm trying to accomplish.  (I'm 2 weeks into learning Swift...)

Comment: @rmaddy I rephrased the question.  Hopefully this is more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should focus on an approach more generic:

```
var tableData: [String: Any?] = ["myNumber": nil, "myList": [Any]()]
var value = tableData["myList"] as? [Any]
value?.insert(["label" : "Example Label A", "timestamp" : NSDate()], at: 0)
tableData["myList"] = value
```